# "required fields missing" error when using Plaid transactions/sync Python API

Tags: python, transactions, plaid

I'd like to write a command line app that fetches transactions.  I used the Quickstart in Sandbox mode to generate an access token, and now I'd like my Python program to call `transactions_sync` to get the transactions.  My Python code is very close to what is shown in the Plaid docs for Transactions.

I was able to make a `TransactionsSyncRequest` object using the access token from the Quickstart and my client and secret IDs.  But when I pass it to `transaction_sync` the response is Bad Request (status code 400), and the message says the `client_id` field is missing.

Is there some sort of initialization step I need to run from Python before calling `transaction_sync`?

I'm using Python 3.10.6, Plaid 18.2.0, running on macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `client_id` field is set when you initialize the PlaidApi object, so there's probably an issue with that part of your code.  Take a look at the [plaid-python readme](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-python/blob/master/README.md) and the full code (not just the `/transactions/sync` part) of the Python Quickstart for examples of how to initialize PlaidApi. For example, here's the excerpt from the README showing how it's done:

```
import plaid
from plaid.api import plaid_api

configuration = plaid.Configuration(
    host=plaid.Environment.Sandbox,
    api_key={
        'clientId': client_id,
        'secret': secret,
    }
)

api_client = plaid.ApiClient(configuration)
client = plaid_api.PlaidApi(api_client)
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  That's pretty much what I was doing.  My stripped down code is shown below.  It has only has two parts, setting up the Plaid API (the code above) and making the call to `transactions_sync`.

Comment: The capitalization in your example doesn't match the correct capitalization in the sample code.